# Python: Convert string form with unicode of namedtuple to namedtuple

Tags: python, string, namedtuple

I have a namedtuple defined as follows:

```
Job = namedtuple("Job", ['name', 'type', 'status', 'ended', 'id', 'baseMetaPath', 'updated', 'archiveUnarchive'])
```

I have a list of namedtuples stored in a file that I am trying to load. I have separated the list into each job object, but the object is still a string. I want to convert the string to the namedtuple object. The string is the following:

```
"Job(name=u'MyJob', type=u'datamart', status=u'complete', ended=152717815282, id=u'2001840', baseMetaPath=u'/datamarts/2001546', updated=1527178152000, archiveUnarchive=0)"
```

Note the unicode inside the string.

Is there a way to directly convert this string to a Job namedtuple type object, or do I have to manually go through, parse the string, and do it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use eval() please follow the official documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval or https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

```
x = 1
eval('x+1')
```

As your request

```
eval("Job(name=u'MyJob', type=u'datamart', status=u'complete', ended=152717815282, id=u'2001840', baseMetaPath=u'/datamarts/2001546', updated=1527178152000, archiveUnarchive=0")
```

Comment: Well, exec didn't work, but eval did, Thank you for the link to the documentation.

Comment: @AlphaBravo it worked because you passed a dictionary. as my answer was for a string. I've updated the answer.